VS code configuration for Pythagora that causing environment error
I am getting the following error in VS code everytime I try to start a new project!
Error: spawn \gpt-pilot\venv\Scripts\python ENOENT
what could be the issue I wonder!
Install Python and pip, and worked fine, but  think something wrong in VS code configuration.

Welcome to SO! Have you searched and tested previous answers before posting your question? Your problem looks very similar to VSCode on discover tests Error: spawn python ENOENT. Anything in there helping?
